# Modify the Tags (Categories) Administration page

Tags: contacts, tags, administer

I'm using CiviCRM 4.7.9 in a Drupal 7 environment. CiviCRM does an amazing amount of stuff remarkably well. Unfortunately, its Tags (Categories) Administration page (http:///civicrm/admin/tag) page is not one of them. I have a rather extensive set of tags organized into tag sets.

When I attempt to manage my tags, the Description column is so wide that it forces everything else off the page. You have to scroll way over to get to the incredibly important Parent ID, Tag set? and actions columns. When you scroll over, you loose all ability to see which tag you're actually dealing with. The whole thing is a terribly clumsy, difficult mess.

If I could just get rid of the totally unnecessary Description column in the display, it would not only make managing the tags (and tag sets) much easier, it would also make it possible. Is there any way of getting the offending Description column disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we have come to a necessity of Tags Administration page changes, only way we've been able to find, was custom CRM/Admin/Page/Tag.tpl template creation. With more than 2000 tags, it was almost impossible to load the page, so we got rid of some CiviCRM stuff and replace it by "native" Datatable script (CiviCRM uses it anyway, but wraps it into set of features we didn't need at the moment). 
This is how it looks now, loads pretty fast and has only information we use (guess Tag Set and Reserved also can be stripped though): 
[image]

It's CiviCRM 4.6, but guess this part has no significant differences to 4.7 
So, you might want to give "custom CiviCRM template creation" a try, most likely you will get there sooner or later, if you continue to use CiviCRM for a long enough :-)

Comment: nice work. are you planning on adding a link for people to grab a copy of the file?

Comment: That's fantastic! I had thought about changing the page template early on, but I'd always like to find a better solution than tampering with the core. Guess there just any other way sometimes.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Sure thing, please advice how it will be better to arrange. It's funny, we've been asked for 4hrs * $120/hr for this modification at CiviCRM forum almost year ago.. So now I'm happy to give something back and be among those "... 2% of users donate before downloading.." via such kind of non-direct donation.

Comment: @LarryTX  It's not exactly a core modification: you plant a copy of core file in a separate location, preserving it from any further core updates and getting a full control of it's content. Some parts of CiviCRM are truly brilliant (some are at the opposite side of the specter though).